# how to set a value to a specific widget children

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Hi guys im new with kivy, im making a small code which will take the input value and set it to the widget children value.

The goal is that when ever i click the add button, 1st row widget will added and will take the value of the TextInput. And If i change the TextInput value and click add button, a 2nd row of widget will be added and it will have the new TextInput value.

Please refer to my code:

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button


kv_string = Builder.load_string(''' 

<CustomRemBtn>:
    Button:
        id: remBtn
        text: 'Remove'

<CostumWidget>:
    TextInput:
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 150
    TextInput:
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 150

<MScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos: root.x,root.top-self.height
            id: main_add
            text: 'Add'
            size_hint: .1,.05
            on_release: root.add_customWidget(True)
        TextInput:
            pos: root.x,root.top-main_add.height-self.height
            id: textIn
            size_hint: .3,.05

            ''')

class CustomRemBtn(BoxLayout):
    def remove(self):
        self.parent.removeFunction()

class CostumWidget(BoxLayout):
    def labelers(self):
        self.parent.floatbase()

class Float_Layout(FloatLayout):
    def floatbase(self):
        self.parent.add_customWidget()
    def removeFunction(self):
        self.parent.remove_customWidget()

class AddRem(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(AddRem,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.count = 0
        self.customLayout = Float_Layout()
        self.add_widget(self.customLayout)

class MScreen(Screen,AddRem):
    def add_customWidget(self,*args):
        self.y1 = (self.top - ((self.count+1)*40)-110)

        self.count += 1
        self.custWidgets = CostumWidget(size_hint=(.1,.05), pos=(100, 480-(self.count*30))) 
        self.removeBtn = CustomRemBtn(size_hint=(.1,.05), pos=(400, 480-(self.count*30)))

        if self.count == 1:
            self.customLayout.add_widget(self.custWidgets)
            self.customLayout.add_widget(self.removeBtn)
        else:
            self.customLayout.remove_widget(self.customLayout.children[0])
            self.customLayout.add_widget(self.custWidgets)
            self.customLayout.add_widget(self.removeBtn)

        for i2 in self.customLayout.children:
            for x in range(len(i2.children)):
                i2.children[x].text=self.ids.textIn.text
                print(i2.children[x].text)


class myApp1(App):
    def build(self):
        return SManage

SManage = ScreenManager()
SManage.add_widget(MScreen())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp1().run()
```

but my problem is that it doesnt work with my code and im stuck, everytime i change the value of the TextInput, all the widget children will have the same value.

Thank you and im hoping for solution or any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would create one class called Row for example. Then when the add button in that row is pushed, it will call a method in the root class to add an other Row to itself, with the wanted parameters.
Like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''

<Row>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        text: root.inp
    Button:
        text: 'Add'
        on_release:
            app.root.add(input.text)
    TextInput:
        id: input

''')


class Row(BoxLayout):
    inp = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self,inp,**kwargs):
        super(Row,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.inp = inp


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyLayout,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.add_widget(Row("First added"))

    def add(self,inp):
        self.add_widget(Row(inp))


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


MyApp().run()
```